# E-mails disappear from mailbox via Outlook but not via OWA

Tags: exchange, outlook, windows-sbs-2011

I have a problem with disappearing email messages from Outlook. Scenario: One day user have all emails in his mailbox and suddenly many of these messages revealed to be missing. When user logs via OWA all of the messages are in place (in Outlook they are still not).We have Microsoft Windows SBS 2011 with Outlook (2010-2013) clients. We have about 40 clients but this problem occurs only on a few of them.

I have tried the following:

- [New-MailboxRepairRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625226(v=exchg.160).aspx)
- Re-configure, re-sync Outlook.
- Reinstall Outlook.

Please help.

Comment: Have you check period of time what email's are kept on pc?
Maybe you have setup month or something? Also check auto archiv?

Comment: Time to Cache object is the thing you're proberbly searching for - auto archives shouldn't be displayed inside of OWA.

Comment: There is no "Time to Cache" setting in Outlook 2010.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/278935)

Comment: Do you see the same if Outlook is in online mode and not cached mode?

Comment: @smwk yes I do.

Answer (score 3):

If the emails are in OWA, then they are in the mailbox.
That suggests the issue is with Outlook only. My instinct is a view is hiding the emails. Reset the views.

outlook.exe /cleanviews

Comment: Ok, I've checked it. Nothing has changed.